# pytest AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'get_marker'

Tags: python, pytest

I have this code in my `conftest.py`:

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    items.sort(key=lambda x: 2 if x.get_marker('slow') else 1)
```

Lately it started to cause these exceptions:

```
$ venv/bin/py.test  -vv --tb=short tests
============================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.6, pytest-4.1.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1 -- /Users/.../venv/bin/python3.5
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/..., inifile:
collecting ... INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/.../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 203, in wrap_session
...
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/.../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/.../tests/conftest.py", line 14, in pytest_collection_modifyitems
INTERNALERROR>     items.sort(key=lambda x: 2 if x.get_marker('slow') else 1)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/.../tests/conftest.py", line 14, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     items.sort(key=lambda x: 2 if x.get_marker('slow') else 1)
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'get_marker'

======================================================================= no tests ran in 0.30 seconds ================================================
```

Comment: Issue link [pytest:252](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov/issues/252) it's compatible issue between `pytest 4.1.0+` to `pytest-cov 2.6.0`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pytest has changed its API in version 4.

Quick solution: use `get_closest_marker()` instead of `get_marker()`:

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    items.sort(key=lambda x: 2 if x.get_closest_marker('slow') else 1)
```

See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/4564

> Remove `Node.get_marker(name)` the return value was not usable for more than a existence check.
>
> Use `Node.get_closest_marker(name)` as a replacement.
>
> Remove `testfunction.markername` attributes - use `Node.iter_markers(name=None)` to iterate them.

Answer (score 0):

Latest documentation suggests using *item.iter_markers*

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#reading-markers-which-were-set-from-multiple-places

```
# content of conftest.py
import sys


def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    for mark in item.iter_markers(name="glob"):
        print("glob args={} kwargs={}".format(mark.args, mark.kwargs))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score -2):

Got this error on a very simple test using `pytest version 4.6.3`. On searching, I came across this [link](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4608) where I found the suggestion below and implemented it.

`pip install pytest==3.10.1`

It worked straight away.
I think this should be as a result of the changes mentioned by @Messa his answer.